# How to create Search Box without using plug-ins?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, search-box

I'm new to this and doing some research on how to create a Search Box from scratch (without using plug-ins like Google, etc).

The idea is to search within a particular website NOT all websites like Google does. Search results need to be displayed on that particular website.

Preferably using JS and PHP.

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

its pretty simple.
from javascript/DOM you need: onkeypress or onkeyup.
plus ajax technology to send it while user is on your page ( without redirects. but I think its better to *not* use ajax in this subject )
from php you need an "handler" script which 
will get your requests from your search field ( input type=text ) and search data in your DB using simple SELECT (you can use LIKE option).
and then you fetch all results form your request to your result page.

Comment: if you will try this without ajax tech, then its goes to a simple HTML form, which is very very simple thing ;)